# How to run Junit5 and TestNG togather in Maven pom

Tags: maven, testng, junit5

I have some set of test cases configured with TestNG. I developed preconditions in junit5 and this has to be run before the test starts. So I wanted to run in sequence Line Precondition(junit5) and then Testcases.
I am using dependency for Junit5 and TestNG7 in PM.XML. Below is a snapshot of POM.xml htmlunitTest.java is for junit5 and testng.xml for TestNGTest cases. while running build is terminating successfully without execution of any test.

Comment: Does it answer to your question.  https://www.tutorialspoint.com/testng/testng_run_junit_tests.htm

Comment: You can not do it using Junit5 & TestNG. TestNG support running Junit4 cases though

Answer (score 1):

You probably do not want to hear my answer. It is the best I have anyway: Don’t take that route! Don’t couple two frameworks that are not made to work together.

Although there might be a convoluted and hacky way to achieve what you describe, you’re setting yourself up for unnecessary technical complexity. Stick with one framework and use its own means for preconditions or fixing a test order.

Comment: What do you mean by "route". There are cases where your project already exists under testNG and you need to bring in technology that has its testing designed for JUnit. You still have to continue testing your code but you cannot simply migrate everything to JUnit and you can't touch the new stuff because it's not yours (opensource library or framework).

Comment: Some technologies do not mix well. JUnit and testng belong into this category.